# What is the Big O of function

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

Current I am learning Data Structures and Algorithms. I want to know how to calculate space complexity and Big O of function. I have written a program that Capabilities first alphabet of each index of an array. Please suggest me better way of doing it.

```js
function capitalizeFirst(arr){
    let result = [];
    function helper(array) {
        if (array.length === 0) return;
        let upperCassed = array[0][0].toUpperCase();
        array[0].split(array[0][0])
        array[0] = array[0].split(array[0][0])
        array[0][0] = upperCassed
        result.push(array[0].join(''));
        helper(array.splice(1));
    }


    helper(arr);
    return result;
}
console.log(capitalizeFirst(['banana', 'orange', 'mango']));

// ['banana', 'orange', 'mango']
// ['Banana', 'Orange', 'Mango']
```

Comment: I think this has O(1) as it never loops and it only ever accessed the first item.

Comment: @evolutionxbox except it is recursive over the entire array. Thereofre must be `O(n)`  (I think!)

Comment: @Jamiec good spot. I didn’t notice the call after the result push.

Comment: It's O(n) as it touches each element and each element only once. And operation for each element is O(1), so overall, it takes O(n)

Comment: I got the point. Thanks Alot @evolutionxbox

Comment: @HamzaKhursheed you’re welcome but it was Jamiec who solved it ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this question. You can use arrow function or javascript function. Below is one possible solution:

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(strArr) {
  strArr.forEach(function (item, index) {
   console.log(item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1));
  });
}

capitalizeFirstLetter(['banana','mango']);
```

Regarding the space complexity, it is the maximum memory space required by the algorithm and in this case, we are not using any extra space. Hence it is O(1).

For more details on time and space complexity you can refer: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/complexity-analysis/time-and-space-complexity/tutorial/

Comment: Thanks Alot :). I am trying to get better in programming.

Comment: You might be right about space complexity (I'm not sure TBH) but usualy we're interested in time complexity.

Comment: @Jamiec You are right. Most of the times time complexity is considered. As the question specifically asked for space complexity for the function I highlighted only that. Time complexity for this will be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Your method works, but for the purpose of calculating Big O I think it is rather complex. It tends to hide the fact that it just loops over an array one time, which would make it `O(n)`.

A simpler way is do exactly what the requirement asks, and only that - loop over the array capitalizing the first character of the string

```js
function capitalizeFirst(arr){
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      arr[i] = arr[i][0].toUpperCase() + arr[i].substring(1);
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(capitalizeFirst(['banana', 'orange', 'mango']));

// ['banana', 'orange', 'mango']
// ['Banana', 'Orange', 'Mango']
```

There are, of course, many ways to write the above but a simple loop, with 2 simple string methods is probably the most straightforward. It is clear from this example that it is `O(n)` for the loop plus `O(1)` for each string operation - the result being still `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks Alot :) I am trying to get better in programming.